# Qt, Error (malloc) when adding mulitple widgets with qcustomplots to window

Tags: c++, qt, widget, malloc, qcustomplot

I am trying to make a Widget that contains multiple widgets with each a QCustomplot and some Plot Data (QLabel and QPushbuttons). This widget is open from a mainwindow with `parent=0`. 
I add the subwidgets with a function, but if it is used more than one time it throws an error:

> malloc.c:3757: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long) (size) >=
>   (unsigned long) (nb)' failed.

So heres the code, that leads to this:

Opening the widget, that should contain the subwidgets:

```
Zeitdatenfenster = new Plotfenster();
Zeitdatenfenster->getZeitData(ausgewaehlteKanaele, *messdaten, double(Anfangszeiteingabe->value()), double(Endzeiteingabe->value()));
Zeitdatenfenster->show();
```

Zeitdatenfenster is in the MainWindow class header : Plotfenster* Zeitdatenfenster;

Constructor:

```
Plotfenster::Plotfenster(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Plotfenster)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    counter=0;
}
```

`getZeitData( ...)` -function:

```
void Plotfenster::getZeitData(const std::vector<bool>& Kanalauswahl, const Messdatenverwaltung& messdaten, double Anfangszeit, double Endzeit){
    setWindowTitle("Time Data");
    int zahler=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<Kanalauswahl.size();i++){
         if(Kanalauswahl[i]){
                Ploteigenschaften* kanalzeit = new Ploteigenschaften();
                std::cout << kanalzeit << std::endl;
                geplotteteDatenInhalt.push_back(kanalzeit);
                geplotteteDatenInhalt[zahler]->setZeitData(messdaten, i,Anfangszeit,Endzeit);
                addPlot(geplotteteDatenInhalt[zahler],zahler);
                zahler++;
          }
    }
}
```

`geplotteteDatenInhalt` is a `std::vector<Ploteigenschaften*>`, 
`addPlot()` is the function where the subwidgets are created. `Ploteigenschaften` is just a class that stores the data that is plottet and functions to change it.(with the two Qvectors added to the qcustomplot)

AddPlot function:

```
void Plotfenster::addPlot(Ploteigenschaften* plotDaten, int zahler ){
       Plot* aktuellerPlot = new Plot(plotDaten, this);
       geplottetes.push_back(aktuellerPlot);
       ui->plotcontainer->addWidget(geplottetes[zahler],counter);
       counter++;
}
```

Plot is the subwiget that contains the constuctor:

```
Plot::Plot(Ploteigenschaften* plotDatens, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Plot)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->plotGrid->setColumnStretch(1, 3);
    ui->plotGrid->setHorizontalSpacing(20);
    derPlot = new QCustomPlot(this);
    this->plotDaten = plotDatens;
    this->Datensetzten();
}
```

The programm crashes at the QCustomplot constructor.
In Datensetzten the plot is specified:

```
void Plot::Datensetzten(){
    this->setInfoText();
    this->setPlot();
    this->setSaveButton();
}
void Plot::setPlot(){
    derPlot->addGraph();
    derPlot->graph(0)->setData(plotDaten->xDaten,plotDaten->yDaten);
    derPlot->xAxis->setRange(plotDaten->xUntereGrenze,plotDaten->xObereGrenze);
    derPlot->yAxis->setRange(plotDaten->yMinimum-std::abs(plotDaten->yMinimum)*0.01,plotDaten->yMaximum+std::abs(plotDaten->yMaximum)*0.01);
    derPlot->xAxis->setLabel(plotDaten->BeschriftungxAchse);
    derPlot->yAxis->setLabel(plotDaten->BeschriftungyAchse);
    derPlot->xAxis2->setVisible(true);
    derPlot->xAxis2->setTickLabels(false);
    derPlot->yAxis2->setVisible(true);
    derPlot->yAxis2->setTickLabels(false);
    ui->plotGrid->addWidget(derPlot,0,1,2,1);
    derPlot->show();
}
```

Sorry for the long post, but I have no idea where the error is located and would be very glad for som ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: How much of each *thing* are you allocating? How many objects are allocated? Have you tried using a memory debugger tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check for memory errors (boffer over- or under-flows etc)?

Comment: About four or five. Less than twenty.
I use the degugger of QT Creator, but I am not familiar with the details of heap allocation.

Comment: Which of your code lines exactly causes the assertion error? `derPlot = new QCustomPlot(this)`?

Comment: Yes, that's the line.
(At least in my class. In the QCustomplot class the line is different each time)